# ubuntu 12.04 - fuser high cpu

Tags: 12.04, php, cpu, cpu-load

The problem is fuser high cpu and server load high.

```
root      20   0  7580  840  692 D   10  0.0   0:00.31 fuser 16061

root      20   0  7580  844  692 D   10  0.0   0:00.31 fuser 16062

root      20   0  7584  840  692 R    9  0.0   0:00.28 fuser 16063

root      20   0  7584  840  692 R    8  0.0   0:00.26 fuser 16054 

root      20   0  7584  840  692 D    8  0.0   0:00.25 fuser 16057 

root      20   0  7580  840  692 D    8  0.0   0:00.25 fuser 16059 

root      20   0  7580  840  692 D    8  0.0   0:00.25 fuser 16056 

root      20   0  7580  840  692 D    8  0.0   0:00.24 fuser 16060 

root      20   0  7580  836  692 D    8  0.0   0:00.24 fuser 16058 

root      20   0  7580  836  692 D    6  0.0   0:00.19 fuser 16064 

root      20   0  7584  836  692 R    5  0.0   0:00.17 fuser
```

I find the question:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11456671

It's a 11.10 bug? but my server is 12.04

my server /etc/cron.d/php5

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

and set to

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
```

also does not work.

quesiton:

1. Change /etc/cron.d/php5 will cause the problem?
2. Now, How do I locate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

maybe old post but.

I have the same problem with ubuntu servers, but no problem with debian servers, the only difference I found was

**ubuntu**

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

**debian**

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -ignore_readdir_race -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

So try adding the `-ignore_readdir_race` to the cron line and I think it will work,